# Creating Formula (Effective-Discontinue) Dates while using vlookup

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I need some help in creating an effective formula to help me return a result into a field if the effective date is within the results column. Also want the formula to be calculated if the discontinue date has not expired.

Here is a snapshot of what I am looking to do. 
[Project](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=n4b5o1&s=8)

Where as "T" will only return if effective date is 04/01/2015-04/30/2015 and still within the discontinue date. 
(T calculates by looking up a part number volume for that given month)
I hope this is clear.

Thank you.

Comment: By "still within the discontinue date", do you mean if today is not yet the discontinue date?

Comment: No, I want the value to be returned if within the effective to discontinue date. After discontinue date has occurred-then no results into that column.

Comment: You're being very vague.  Could you fill in these words really specifically?  "I want (what value) to be returned if (what, exactly) is between (value in which column) and (value in which other column).  After (what value, exactly) has passed the discontinue date, nothing needs to be returned."

Comment: What I am looking for is effective pricing delta, so I want T column to return a the calculated value of receipts times the delta, if the effective date is within that month for this instance 04/01

Comment: "I want (Delta times vlookup) to be returned if (effective, column K) is within column T (ie 04/01/2015-04/31/2015). No result to be reported if L has come to that specific column.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks.  If L is in the middle of some month, should that month still report?  Also, if Effective is 4/15/15 and Discontinue is 9/15, should T report during June?

Comment: Yes L should report if falls within that month. Certainly for the second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this will do what you want:

```
=IF(AND(A2<=DATEVALUE("4/30/2015"),B2>=DATEVALUE("4/1/2015")),"Your function here","")
```

You'd get rid of the quotes for "Your function here" and replace it with your delta*vlookup formula.

If you formatted the column heading so it was just the first day of a given month (4/1/2015), you could automate the formula so that you don't have to adjust it for each month column.