# Performing Excel functions based on effective/discontinued dates

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a question that's somewhat similar to the one asked here.

[Creating Formula (Effective-Discontinue) Dates while using vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097250/creating-formula-effective-discontinue-dates-while-using-vlookup)

Basically, I have two tables:

1. Historical sales data per item (with sales dates)
2. Items eligible for commission along with effective/discontinued dates

What I need is some way to calculate commission per item into my first table based on the eligible commission items in the second table.  The part of my question that differs from the link I provided is that any one of my sales items might have multiple effective/discontinued dates, meaning that item 12345 might be effective 1/1/2015-3/31/2015 and also 4/15/2015-current, so a sale of the item on 4/1/2015 would be ineligible for a commission, but sales on 3/1/2015 and 5/1/2015 would be eligible.

Does anyone have suggestions on formulas I can use and ways to organize my data in table 2 to best facilitate what I'm trying to do?  Thanks.

Edit: Here are some tables with sample data.

Table 1 (sales data):

```
InvoiceDate ItemCode    QuantityShipped
1/1/2015    123456      100
2/1/2015    789456      100
3/1/2015    789456      300
4/1/2015    123456      200
5/1/2015    123456      300
```

Table 2 (item eligibility data):

```
Item Code   Effective Date  Discontinued Date   Commission Rate
123456      1/1/2015        3/1/2015            0.02
123456      4/15/2015                           0.03
789456      3/1/2015                            0.02
```

Comment: Would help to show some (small) samples of your data, preferably as text and not screenshots, so there's no need to re-type the values if someone wants to try out a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've added samples.

Answer (score 1):

Entered in E3 as an array formula (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter)
I'm not great at this part of excel so I'm sure there are better approaches.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm having a hard time translating your solution into something that works with table structured references (which would make things much easier for me to work with).  When I try to substitute each range with the equivalent table structured reference, the formula no longer works for me.  Would you happen to know why and would you happen to have a workaround?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it was an error on my part while translating your solution (see my comments for Scott's solution; I did the same thing with yours).

Answer (score 0):

Try this index/match:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$4,MATCH(1,IF(($G$2:$G$4<=A2)*(IF($H$2:$H$4<>"",$H$2:$H$4,TODAY())>=A2)*($F$2:$F$4=B2),1,0),0)),0)
```

It is an array, so Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

[image]

For table references:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Commission Rate],MATCH(1,IF((Table1[Effective Date]<=[@InvoiceDate])*(IF(Table1[Discontinued Date]<>"",Table1[Discontinued Date],TODAY())>=[@InvoiceDate])*(Table1[Item Code]=[@ItemCode]),1,0),0)),0)
```

Still an array formula so ***you must use Ctrl-Shift-Enter*** to confirm the formula instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  After pasting the formula in the formula bar and making the needed changes hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to implement your solution using structured references but it's not translating.  Would you happen to have a solution that allows for structured references?

Comment: @JonathanL. Do you mean table references?

Comment: Yes, table references.  Thanks.

Comment: Sigh, I had a feeling I was forgetting something and as soon as I saw your edited solution I knew what it was.  I had forgotten to include the @ for the singular references as I was manually typing in the formula.  I added those and now everything works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JonathanL. now you need to chose one to mark as correct.  It is something only you can do, select the formula you are using as the correct.  Neither Tim nor myself will have our feelings hurt if you choose the other.  Click on the grey/green heck mark by the answer.